# Centos Installation base environment only showing basic functions

Tags: linux, centos, login

I am currently interested in learning how Linux works. I have followed the tutorial [How to Install CentOS 7 on VMware Workstation 14 Pro?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsXQwnnL4bI) The problem is, every time I install the only available **Base Environment** is the *Minimal Function*.

[image: Base Environment]

Aside from this, I can't seem to login to my credentials after installation. Why is that?

Below are the procedures I did:

This is the adding of user
[image]

After that, I was brought here
[image]

HEre is the login so I typed what I created in my user accounts
[image]

After typing, I am always brought here.
[image]

If I try to use root, it always procs Login incorrect.

Thanks.

Comment: What image file are you using for the installation? I'm thinking that may be the reason you only see the option for a minimal install.

Comment: @BrianZ It is a .iso

Comment: Good, but which .iso? It looks like you are using the "minimal" one, while another one (like [the "DVD" image](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1810.iso)) might be more appropriate.

Comment: @BrianZ Yes I am using the minimal version

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root account isn't allowed to login for security reasons. click the box where it says make account administrator. Also change the password from sample to something else. (I think that may be your problem)

Comment: I have created a new virtual machine but still the same error persist. But I have noticed, once the installation is complete, I am not directed to the License Agreement part. It directs me to the login phase(was it due to having only minimal options?).